# Python 2.7.8 - Dictionary to file and back with style

Tags: file, python-2.7, dictionary, save, load

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.bok = {'peter': 123, 'maria': 321, 'harry': 888}

 def save(self):
    file = open('test.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(self.bok))
    file.close()
    print "File was successfully saved."

 def load(self):
    try:
        file = open('test.txt', 'r')
        newdict = eval(file.read())
        self.bok = newdict
        file.close()
        print "File was successfully loaded."
    except IOError:                                 
        print "No file was found."
        return
```

How do i make it look like this inside the text file:
value1:key1
value2:key2
==>
123:peter
321:maria
Currently it looks like normal, a dictionary:
{'peter': 123, 'maria': 321, 'harry': 888}
But the issue that would appear is to load the file since it doesn't look like a dictionary anymore?

(Load = loads the dictionary from a .txt file to self.bok{})
(Save = saves the dictionary to a .txt file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

def save(self, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as fout:
        outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=":")
        for k,v in self.bok.iteritems():
            outfile.writerow([v,k])

def load(self, filepath):
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        print "No file was found"
        return
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        for v,k in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=":"):
            self.bok[k] = v
```

Without any help from `csv`:

```
def save(self, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for k,v in self.bok.iteritems():
            outfile.write("{}:{}\n".format(v,k))

def load(self, filepath):
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        print "No file was found"
        return
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            v,k = line.strip().split(":")
            self.bok[k] = v
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without importing anything? ;)

Comment: @Widdin: check it out